# How to properly resize a UIView used throughout the project for a universal app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to do an error message view "something like Facebook app when there is bad network connection" that could be used across all view controllers in the project. 
So I created a .xib file with a label (error message) and a close button.

Here is the class that is managing the UIView:

```
class ErrorMessageView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ErrorMessageView", owner: self, options: nil)
        guard let content = contentView else { return }
        content.frame = self.frame
        self.addSubview(content)
    }

    @IBAction func cancelAction(sender: UIButton) {
        self.hidden = true
    }

    class func setupErrorView(tableView: UITableView) -> ErrorMessageView {

        // Initialize an Error Message View
        let errorMessageView = ErrorMessageView()
        tableView.addSubview(errorMessageView)

        // Setup its constraints
        errorMessageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: errorMessageView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        tableView.addConstraint(topConstraint)

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: errorMessageView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        tableView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: errorMessageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 44.0)
        errorMessageView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        errorMessageView.hidden = true

        return errorMessageView
    }
}
```

The last class function is invoked in each view controller where there could be a network connection error and if the error happens I just show the `ErrorMessageView`.

It shows perfectly placed as intended on both iPhone and iPad all orientations - But on the iPhone I get a complicated constraints' error (although the view appears alright in the simulator!". This is the error I get!

```
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9bd6e0 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7fccda9b6da0.width == Arti.ErrorMessageView:0x7fccda9b4b70.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9b7590 UILabel:0x7fccda9b6f10'TEST ERROR MESSAGE VIEW'.leading == UIView:0x7fccda9b6da0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9b7680 H:[UILabel:0x7fccda9b6f10'TEST ERROR MESSAGE VIEW']-(NSSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x7fccda9b67a0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9b76d0 H:[UIButton:0x7fccda9b67a0]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fccda9b6da0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9aaca0 UITableView:0x7fccd890e400.leading == UIView:0x7fccda9aa180.leading>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9aad40 UITableView:0x7fccd890e400.trailing == UIView:0x7fccda9aa010.trailing>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9aade0 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x7fccd890e400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fccda9a9ea0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9aae30 UIView:0x7fccda9aa180.width == UIView:0x7fccda9aa010.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9aae80 H:[UIView:0x7fccda9aa180]-(NSSpace(8))-[UIView:0x7fccda9a60e0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9aaf20 UIView:0x7fccda9a60e0.centerX == UIView:0x7fccda9a9ea0.centerX>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9ab150 H:[UIView:0x7fccda9a60e0]-(NSSpace(8))-[UIView:0x7fccda9aa010]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9ba8c0 UITableView:0x7fccd890e400.width == Arti.ErrorMessageView:0x7fccda9b4b70.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccda9bf9a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fccda9a9ea0(0)]>"
```

)

Comment: It seems you have a problem with the constraints (inside the xib file). I a not sure why it refers to a UITableView though. Are all errors you show us coming from the alert you are popping ?

Comment: Yes, the errors are all related to the `ErrorMessageView`, the table view is what the error appears atop of... Yet, you may well be right, the xib file size is Freeform - Its width in IB is 600. Could that be the cause? On iPad there are no errors, only iPhone... If yes, how could that be resolved? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

From your description and the log, I would say that your view is wider than the UITableView you're putting it into. That could be why you only get the error on the narrower iPhone screen.

To test if that's the case, change your xib width to the smallest size you may display this view in the app and check if your constraints are ok.

Comment: I just followed your advice. Same error appears!. I even changed to the xib file size in Simulated Metrics of the Attributes Inspector to be Inferred. Same error...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add the Constraints in the .xib, so you can see which Constraint is wrong. Xcode will mark them with red dots or yellow dots.

1. Adjust the view size in .xib file, make it equal to the frame size when you init the error message view.
2. remove all the Constraints, and add them again in .xib.

Comment: I have constraints set in the xib file for the label and close button (subviews of the `contentView` in the code above). These are alright. The constraints written in code in the above class are inevitable! Because the `UIView` in the xib file needs to be resized according to the `UIViewController` it will appear on top of.

Comment: I see. Then, you need to show the Constraints that you set in the xib file.

Comment: Here is [a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbp188pouici8c8/Screenshot%202015-12-25%2010.30.13.png?dl=0) of the xib file including the constraints.